# Lumen Artisan command throws "Error: Call to a member function assertExitCode() on int" while testing

Tags: laravel, testing, command, phpunit, lumen

my code is as follows:

```
class DailyUsageCommandTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testDailyUsageCommandTest()
    {
        $this->artisan('daily-usage')->assertExitCode(0);
    }
}
```

But it throws:

> 1) DailyUsageCommandTest::testDailyUsageCommandTest
> Error: Call to a member function assertExitCode() on int

Comment: Mark it as correct please !

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying that `$this->artisan('daily-usage')` returns an `int` (Call to a member function assertExitCode() on `int`). So you have to store the result and do `assertTrue` with your value like this:

```php
$result = $this->artisan('daily-usage');

$this->assertTrue($result === 0);
```